# Expanding particles by the normals of the sphere they are scattered on GeoNodes Simulation zones

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I want to instance points on a sphere and use the normals of the sphere to make the particles expand from that point, if possible make them collide with objects around them using simulation node in GeoNodes.